# How to generate signed APKs from an AAB with only the PEM certificate?

Tags: android

I have a signed AAB and the .pem certificate I want to generate the APKs (or a universal APK) but they are signed.

I used [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) but if you don't send it information from the keystore this uses the debug keystore. That's the point, I don't have the keystore.

I think it's totally possible because Google Play and Huawei App Gallery only use these files (AAB and PEM) to generate all the APKs for their stores.

Do I need to create a keystore from the PEM certificate?

Is it possible to use the bundletool with only the PEM?

How does Google Play or Huawei AppGallery to generate the APKs with only these files?

Comment: If you are using Google App signing , the lost Keystore can be recovered. 

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en#reset

Comment: Actually I didn't lose the keystore, the application is from another owner (he has no technical knowledge) whom I want to help generate the APKs for testing purposes without him sending me the keystore (because it is sensitive information)

Comment: Then why don't you ask the client to generate APK's by his own using the commands mentioned the bundletool docs 

bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
--ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
--ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
--ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
--key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd